# When is Self Hosted Table Storage Cheaper than Azure

Tags: mongodb, hosting, azure-storage

I have scoured the web, and can't find any good reports on this. I thought this would be a common question, but I may be wrong (given the lack of data online).

We are building a net new application, and are looking at different NoSQL back-ends.  The two with the most promise (in terms of functionality, market adoption, performance) are Azure Table Storage and MongoDB.  There's no doubt that Azure Table Storage in way cheaper in the short-term when your number of clients (and number of IOps) is low.  But I'm very concerned about vendor-lock if/when our app goes big, and now we're forced to share a sizable chuck of monthly profits, especially if pricing goes up.

I was able to find some some reports on MongoDB host -in Azure VMs- versus Azure table storage, but they were all written by Microsoft Azure MVPs.  While I respect MS MVPs, that's not exactly an unbiased comparison, and isn't what I'm looking for.  I'm looking for a comparison between Azure Table storage, versus a MongoDB cluster hosted in a Colo.  For example, I've read come compelling configs with people running Hadoop or Mongo on SuperMicro 2U machines with 24x internal drives that have amazing IOPs performance and all the same scale-out benefits of Azure Table Storage.

So long story short(er), I'm not surprised that Mongo on Azure VMs are more expensive than Azure table storage. That makes total sense given the way IaaS providers makes money on Table Storage versus VMs.

My question is: at what point (if ever) do inexpensive Mongo nodes in a low-cost hosted data center become cheaper than the monthly cost of Azure Table Storage.  Because that's the entire point of Mongo, right? Your hardware & hosting costs should be a fraction of traditional RDBMS apps since you don't need high-end hosting, expensive SAN storage, etc.  It's intended to be a true clustered data storage system with many inexpensive, redundant nodes.

-OR-

If you believe my comparison of MongoDB and Azure Table Storage is fundamentally flawed (meaning they do not have a comparable feature-sets), then I would love to hear those arguments as well.

Thanks all,

Answer (score 3):

> If you believe my comparison of MongoDB and Azure Table Storage is fundamentally flawed (meaning they do not have a comparable feature-sets), then I would love to hear those arguments as well.

I think the comparison is hard to make for a couple of reasons:
1) Table Storage is a managed No-SQL offering where dynamic load balancing and scale is handled for you with fairly high scale limits (500TB, 20K entities/sec; detailed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn249410.aspx). Vs the Mongo based solution you mention is one where you will have to monitor and scale your Mongo cluster yourself
2) Table Storage is optimized for point lookups where you specify the partition key and row key and certain things like indexing on other entities are harder to do. Mongo on the other hand is a JSON document store with better support for ad hoc queries and indexing on any field.

Also, I'm as biased as if not more so than Azure MVPs since I work on the Azure Storage engineering team :). But I think you have to pick the correct/most efficient solution for your workload. You can probably make Table Storage or Mongo solve your problems but depending on your write and query patterns as well as scale, one might be easier than the other (or some completely different solution might better)